# Radius of convergence of a power serise involving the Fibonacci sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Consider the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n.$$

where, $a_0=0$ , $a_1=1$ , $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$.

Find the radius of convergence of the power series.

***MY Attempt :***

Clearly $\{a_n\}$ is a Fibonacci sequence.

Let, $R$ be the radius of convergence of the power series.

We have , $$\frac{1}{R}=\lim_n\sup\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$$

$$=\lim_n\sup\left|\frac{a_n+a_{n-1}}{a_n}\right|$$

$$1+\lim_n\sup\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\right|.$$

But I can't write $\lim_n\sup\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\right|$ in terms of  $R$ such that we can find out $R$ by solving the equation involving $R$.

> Again we know that the $n$-th term of Fibonacci sequence is $$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left[\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n\right].$$
>
> From this I find that the radius of convergence of the power series is $\frac{2}{1+\sqrt 5}$.
>
> Is this answer correct ?
>
> If **NOT** what is the correct answer ?

But I want to find the radius of convergence **NOT** using the $n$-th term of Fibonacci sequence. How I can find it ?

Please help...

Thanks in Advance.........

Comment: Can you include how that answer $2 \over {1 + \sqrt{5}}$ came ?

Comment: The solution to the recurrence will grow as $\phi^n$ (almost-)regardless of the initial conditions.

Comment: The answer you gave is correct. One could prove that the ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ has a limit, and then the fact it is $\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ follows easily from the recurrence $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$.  Just divide through by $a_{n+1}$. The fact that the limit exists is a bit unpleasant, but doable. It is definitely easier to work with the Binet formula that you quoted.

Comment: I tried in this way..but I can't understand that what is the limit of $\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n+1}}$ & the limit of $\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n+1}}$. If you more details to find the limits then it will helpful to me..

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106362/a-n-series-of-fibonacci-numbers-fx-sum-0-inftya-nxn-show-that-i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us re-write the recurrence relation 
$$a_{n+1} = a_{n} +a_{n-1} $$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}} {a_{n}} = 1+\frac{a_{n-1}} {a_{n}}  $$
Recursion allows us to write
$$\frac{a_{n+1}} {a_{n}} = 1+\frac{1} {1+\frac{a_{n-2}} {a_{n-1}} } $$
One can keep repeating the same to get what is called as a continued fraction which in this case looks like:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}} {a_{n}} = 1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\cdots}}} $$
One should note that it will terminate at some point as we are supposed to get $\frac{a_0 }{a_1}$ at the n-th use of recurrence relation. But since we wish to find limit of the ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}} {a_{n}} $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we can write it as an infinite continued fraction. Now to find the value consider :$$\frac{1} {R} = 1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\cdots}}} = 1 + \frac{1} {\frac{1} {R} } $$
Which yields the quadratic equation:
$$R^2 + R - 1=0$$
The minimum root (absolute value) of which gives us the radios of convergence. I'll leave it to you.

Comment: Please multiply and divide your answer by $\sqrt{5} -1$ and then, if you want, we can discuss. :)

Comment: OK..OK..I find it...It is clear to me now...I did this answer..but did not rationalizing ..